# __thread c++ memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, thread-local

I have a class A like this:

```
class A {
  static __thread Arena * arena;
}
```

if one thread is destroyed or just quit , will the memory which arena take will be released?

Comment: Please don't tag c++ questions as c, they are separate languages

Comment: `__thread` is not standard C++, so you should mention what compiler you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory used by `arena` will be released but whatever it is pointing to won't be freed.

Use c++11's `thread_local` with a smart pointer instead e.g.

```
class A {
  thread_local std::unique_ptr<Arena> arena;
}
```

Comment: With `thread_local`, the `arena` destructor will be called at thread exit. I don't think this is the case for the older compiler-specific `__thread` keyword.

Comment: @prapin i think you're right though i can't find much in the way of documentation